# How can I escape slashes and quotes in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I would like to do the following

```
[controller setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<strong>%@</strong> <br> <br> %@ <br><br> %@ <br><br> Sent From MyApp",self.articleTitle, self.articleDescription, self.articleURL] 
isHTML:YES];
```

on the last %@ I would like to do `<a href="%@">Hello</a>`

But I am not sure how to escape it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
@"....<a href=\"%%@\">Hello</a>..."
```

if you put it in the format, or use

```
@"<a href=\"%@\">Hello</a>"
```

if you include it using `%@` in the format string. The `%@` is only interpreted in the first argument of the `stringWithFormat:` method here.